# Dynamic SQL Connection in SQL Server 2012 views

Tags: sql, dynamic, sql-server-2012, sql-view

I don't really know what to title this question as because I'm not too sure about the exact terminology, however I just wanted to know if it is possible to set up a dynamic database connection inside a view.
We have a view which looks at 2 different databases. The database names are stored in another table, lets say the columns are called dbID1 and dbID2...

```
exampleView
SELECT a.ID, b.name 
FROM db1.dbo.IDNumbers a
INNER JOIN db2.dbo.Employees b ON a.ID = b.ID
```

In the exampleView the databases are hardcoded as db1.dbo and db2.dbo, is it possible to have that db1 or db2 set dynamically based on the values other table? I realize this is probably a silly example but it is just to demonstrate.

Comment: Would you want to have database names as the input parameters (like strings)?

Comment: to be honest I don't really know how to even begin looking for a way to do this... the best I could come up with was using something like this... FROM (SELECT dbID1 FROM settings).IDNumbers